# TextSymbol not working inside Mapview (ESRI ArcGIS 4.3)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The following is my code sample:

I tried rendering the map using the Picture Marker Symbol (as used in the example) and it works pretty well. But if I use `TextSymbol` as mentioned in the documentation inside Graphic object, the application fails with the error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTransform' of undefined and u is
>   undefined.

[image: Using Text Symbol]
[image: Using Picture Marker Symbol]

```
    let mapProperties: any = {
        basemap: "streets",
        ground: "world-elevation"
      };

      let map: any = new Map(mapProperties);
      let constructMap = function (lat, long, popupTemplate) {
        var point = new Point({
          longitude: lat,
          latitude: long
        });
        var markerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
          url: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
          width: "25px",
          height: "41px"
        });


        var textSym = new TextSymbol({
          text: "Sample Text"
        });
        console.log(textSym, markerSymbol);
        var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: markerSymbol,
          popupTemplate: popupTemplate
        });
        var a = new MapView(mapViewProperties);

        a.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/44438402/820534

Comment: Sushant, it seems to work for me - see https://jsbin.com/rubico/edit?html,output - If that doesn't help, could you maybe share a full sample?